# What are some filler words used by younger people in French?

Tags: langage-des-jeunes

In American English, words such as “like” and “literally” have become filler words over the last few decades, and their use as filler words is attached to certain demographics (for example, see this [article](https://www.vanityfair.com/culture/2010/01/hitchens-like-201001) on the history of the use of like as filler word — older speakers would typically not use "like" this way).

What are some similar filler words that are used by younger French speakers nowadays?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too broad.

Comment: I am glad to see that what I hear from my teen children (together with images of a ruined future) is actually common :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to a forum about french trends and french teens/pop culture. Moreover this question is more of a subject of discussion.

Comment: @Lambie I've edited the question to make it clearer and less broad

Answer (score 18):

> Genre (~like)
>
> T'sais (you know)
>
> En fait (~actually)
>
> J'veux dire (~ I mean)
>
> Nan (~nah)
>
> Quoi (~like, at the end of a sentence)

With some *mais* in-between to string them together... Which gives things such as:

> T'sais mais genre en fait, il lui avait pas dit, quoi... (~you know but like actually, he didn't tell her, like)
>
> Nan mais genre j'veux dire, truc de ouf quoi (~No but like I mean, crazy, like)

Comment: the last example is golden (and the overall list +1)

Answer (score 4):

> Du coup (~so/then depending if it is at the begining or the end of the sentence respectively)

Answer (score 3):

> t'inquiètes (*don't worry* or *no worries*)

This is usually the moment when I start to worry.